# Statements on dimension of column spaces and null spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $m\times n$-matrix where $m<n$. Which of these following claims can we conclude with

1) $\textrm{dim}\ \textrm{Col} A>0$

2) $\textrm{dim}\ \textrm{Null} A>0$

I honestly do not know where to start arguing for or against these statements, I know that

$$\textrm{rank}A=\textrm{dim}(\textrm{row}(A))=\textrm{dim}(\textrm{col}(A))$$

But I thought that the rank was reliant on the number of pivots in any echelon form, and without a concrete matrix, I can't really calculate those. So how would I argue against or for these statements?

Comment: For (1), think about $A=0$. For (2): What you said, noting that the rank is the dimension of the column space (the rank is also the dimension of the row space, hence no larger than $m$).

Answer (score 1):

Well, whatever the matrix actually is, given that it has $m$ rows and $n$ columns, we know that it has at most $m$ pivots or that $\dim(\text{Col}(A)) = \text{rank}(A) \le m <n$. We know that $\dim(\text{Null}(A)) + \dim(\text{Col}(A))=n$ by another basic theorem.

So we have a number $< n$ plus $\dim(\text{Null}(A))$ that must equal $n$..